# How to vertically align stdout text in Ruby (like Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stdout, thor

I am trying to create a CLI application and I want to output text to the console. I cannot figure out how to format how I want.

When you type `rails new app`, you get this output:

```
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
     run  bundle install
```

How can I write my output to make sure all the commands are vertically aligned like that?

PS. I am using Thor is that matters.

Thanks

Comment: possibly duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087658/nicely-formatting-output-to-console-specifying-number-of-tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this. They are just printing out lines of text with spacing in between.

```
puts "  create  tmp/cache"
puts "  create  tmp/cache/assets"
# ...
```

will output exactly the same way.

There is a function in Ruby that would help out with this a tiny bit ([`String#rjust`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-rjust)), which will pad the string with spaces on the left. So if you want your first column to be 10 characters wide, you can `rjust` the strings with a value of 10 and it will align them to the right. If you're iterating through a hash, for example, you might run the following code:

```
hash = { "hello" => "world", "foo" => "bar" }
hash.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key.rjust(7)}  #{value}"
end
#  hello  world
#    foo  bar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the venerable `sprintf` in your case. There are a [number of stylistic and utilitarian reasons why](http://batsov.com/articles/2013/06/27/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-2-favor-sprintf-format-over-string-number-percent/), but in general it makes for more concise code. You can also programatically specify the padding you need. In your specific example:

```
output = {create: 'something.rb',
          identical: 'something_else.rb',}
output.each do |key, value|
  puts sprintf '%10s  %3s', key.to_s, value
end
```

gives you

```
   create  something.rb 
identical  something_else.rb
```