# output to columns ruby

Tags: ruby, output

I've written a program to output the user id, user name, and number of logins.  It runs but i can not get it to output in even columns.  This is how the output looks:

```
UserID                  Full Name                       Number of Logins
------                  ---------                       ----------------
*******b                ***** *******                   32
********t1              ********* ********                      27
********t1              ****** ********                 43

*********k1             ******* ***********                     18
******2                 ****** *****                    14
*********a16                    ****** *********                        6
```

I've tried adjusting the tabs and adding spaces but it doesn't fix the issue.  Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

def executeLast
  userLogin=Hash.new("0")
  lastExecute=IO.popen("last -w", 'r')
  lastExecute.each_line do |line|
    next if line=~/^$/
    next if (line=~/^wtmp*/)
    fields=line.split()
    userid=fields[0]
    userLogin[userid]=userLogin[userid].to_i()+1
  end
  return userLogin
end

def getUserID (userid)
  pw=IO.popen("getent passwd #{userid}", 'r')
  line=pw.gets()
  if (line)
    pwFields=line.split(":")
    print(pwFields[4])
  end
end

userLogin=executeLast
puts("UserID\t\t\tFull Name\t\t\tNumber of Logins")
puts("------\t\t\t---------\t\t\t----------------")
userLogin.each do |key, value|
  print("#{key}    \t\t")
  getUserID(key)
  print("\t\t\t#{value}")
  puts
end
```

Any suggestions to get it to output evenly in the columns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nicely formatting output to console, specifying number of tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087658/nicely-formatting-output-to-console-specifying-number-of-tabs)

Comment: As Gerry says, this thing is in dire need of indentation and proper formatting. This looks like code that was squeezed out of a minimizer.

Comment: Ruby strongly encourages naming variables and methods with all lower-case letters, that is `get_user_id` instead of `getUserId`. Capital letters have specific meaning in Ruby, they define constants like `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: You're also working against yourself here, `Hash.new("0")` creates an array initialized with the string `"0"`. Later you do `userLogin[userid]=userLogin[userid].to_i()+1` which is wasted effort. `Hash.new(0)` and then `user_login[userid] += 1` will do the job. Remember in Ruby that method calls with no arguments have their parens omitted to avoid clutter. `.to_i` should be just that.

Comment: Hint: Use `sprintf` with things like `%6s %5s` etc. to define your columns.

Comment: I was gonna make it work, but I am too lazy to fix variable names and camel case just hurts my eyes.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš, it's not good to modify variable names, or code in general, in a question or answer. Suggesting that it be improved in a comment is fine, and improving grammar and spelling in the text itself is good.

Comment: While using `IO.popen` will work, we usually use backticks for simple calls like that. "[Three Virtues](http://threevirtues.com)" is worth reading; The first virtue leads us to write the least amount of code we have to to accomplish something.